# attribute warn unused result equivalent for visual c

Tags: c++, c, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-warnings

Is there any Visual C equivalent to GCC's `__attribute__((warn_unused_result))`?

I looked for the question, but didn't found results.

[Attribute definition at GNU docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#warn_unused_result).

Answer (score 1):

In C++ there is a standard `[[nodiscard]]` atrbiute available since C++17, otherwise you can use `_Check_return_` [SAL annotation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/annotating-function-behavior?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Can't find that `_Check_return_` attribute in that link, can you give a more precise description or link. This is a useful answer! Thank you.

Comment: @uprego You should just check `_Check_return_` declaration header

Comment: Yeah, yeah, well I can find the attribute now, but only after you edited the link to point to the proper page \~\_\~